# Inner Join, multiplos Inserts com multiplas condições

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, sql-insert

Bom, é o seguinte, não estou entendendo por onde devo começar, se devo primeiro selecionar os clientes, enfim, tenho certeza que vai utilizar `inner join` ou algum `joiner` pois ele utiliza outras tabelas de auxílio. Queria ajuda pra entender como fazer essa query. Segue na imagem a descrição do que deve ser feito.

Segue a estrutura das tabelas:

- tblTicket

  - IdTicket (chave primaria)
  - IdCliente(chave estrangeira)
  - IdEvento(chave estrangeira)
  - data(date)
  - estadoPagamendo(bool)
- tblClientes

  - IdCliente
  - Sexo
  - Nome
- tblEventos

  - IdEventos
  - Nome

[image: Descrição das condições dos inserts]

Comment: a estrutura da tabela ticket tem idticket, idcliente(chave estrangeira, idatracao(chave estrangeira), data e pago(bool)

Comment: Victor, poderia editar sua pergunta e colocar a estrutura de todas as tabelas envolvidas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece ser um exercício de banco de dados, até porque o que o enunciado se propõe não faz muito sentido.

Estou supondo que todas as chaves primárias são `IDENTITY`.

A sintaxe básica de inserção é:

```
INSERT INTO tblTickets (IdCliente, IdEvento, data, estadoPagamento)
SELECT ...
```

Repare que não coloquei `IdTicket`. Por ser uma coluna `IDENTITY`, não preciso mencioná-la na sentença.

Também poderia fazer assim:

```
INSERT INTO tblTickets (IdTicket, IdCliente, IdEvento, data, estadoPagamento)
SELECT null, ...
```

O exercício diz:

> Cada cliente comprou um ou dois tickets para cada um dos 20 eventos da Livraria, sendo:
>
> - Um ticket caso o `IdCliente` (sic) for par;
> - Dois tickets caso o `IdCliente` (sic) for ímpar;

A maneira fácil de saber se um número é par ou ímpar é divindo por 2 e verificando se o resto da divisão é zero. Se for, é par. Caso contrário, é ímpar.

Ou seja:

```
SELECT 6 % 2; -- Devolve 0
SELECT 7 % 2; -- Devolve 1
```

Assim, um `SELECT` para trazer todos os clientes com `IdCliente` par seria:

```
SELECT *
from tblClientes
where IdCliente % 2 = 0;
```

E os ímpares:

```
SELECT *
from tblClientes
where IdCliente % 2 = 1;
```

Só que o exercício pede algo que vejo como sem sentido (duas linhas para cada `IdCliente` ímpar). Neste caso, um `UNION ALL` resolve, duplicando as linhas:

```
SELECT *
from tblClientes
where IdCliente % 2 = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
from tblClientes
where IdCliente % 2 = 1
```

Isto não é muito bonito nem performático de fazer, mas funciona.

> O campo `DataDaVenda` deverá ter 01/03/2009 em todos os registros.

Este eu acho que é o mais simples:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/03/2009', 103);
```

> Apenas os clientes do sexo feminino já fizeram o pagamento dos tickets.

Este é uma aplicação da sentença `CASE`:

```
CASE 
    WHEN SEXO = 'M' THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
END
```

Juntando tudo, ficaria algo assim:

```
INSERT INTO tblTickets (IdCliente, IdEvento, data, estadoPagamento)
SELECT c.IdCliente, e.IdEvento, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/03/2009', 103), 
    (CASE
        WHEN c.Sexo = 'M' THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
    END) as EstadoPagamento
FROM tblClientes c
CROSS JOIN tblEventos e
WHERE c.IdCliente % 2 = 0;

INSERT INTO tblTickets (IdCliente, IdEvento, data, estadoPagamento)
SELECT c.IdCliente, e.IdEvento, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/03/2009', 103), 
    (CASE
        WHEN c.Sexo = 'M' THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
    END) as EstadoPagamento
FROM tblClientes c
CROSS JOIN tblEventos e
WHERE c.IdCliente % 2 = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT c.IdCliente, e.IdEvento, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/03/2009', 103), 
    (CASE
        WHEN c.Sexo = 'M' THEN TRUE
        ELSE FALSE
    END) as EstadoPagamento
FROM tblClientes c
CROSS JOIN tblEventos e
WHERE c.IdCliente % 2 = 1;
```

Por fim, `CROSS JOIN` realiza um produto cartesiano entre as duas tabelas relacionadas.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante ;)